# How to say "to apply to university/college"

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

How do you say "I am getting ready to apply to college/university."  Я собираюсь поступать в университет ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Я собираюсь поступ**а**ть в университет* is actually a correct translation.  Another option would be *Я готовлюсь поступать в университет*. This conveys the meaning of *getting ready*.

@kishtibargo's answer incorrectly puts the suggested translation as *Я собираюсь поступ**и**ть в университет* - and then proceeds to correctly explain why this translation is not right.

@kishtibargo's suggestion of *Я собираюсь подать в универ*, while technically correct, is more of a slang.  Your version of *Я собираюсь поступ**а**ть в университет* is a perfectly correct translation.